# Difference between delete and remove method in $resource?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

What is the difference between `delete` and `remove` methods? Both of them use `DELETE` method of HTTP. I couldn't find any reasonable information.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I don't believe there is any difference.   [Angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L510):

```
angular.module('ngResource', ['ng']).
  factory('$resource', ['$http', '$parse', function($http, $parse) {
    var DEFAULT_ACTIONS = {
      'get':    {method:'GET'},
      'save':   {method:'POST'},
      'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
      'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
      'delete': {method:'DELETE'}
```

From Eric W. (his edit was rejected before I could approve it):
AngularJS by Green & Seshadri warns that the delete method may not work in IE unless bracket notation is used (`myResource[delete]()`) as `delete` is a reserved word. So you may want to consider using the `remove` method instead.

Comment: Yeah, Angular still rocks.

Comment: It would be `myResource.$delete()` for an instance, so not sure what the problem is.